# Implementing renaming a document in an OS-X app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

My end goal of this task is to have renaming feature similar to [what Pages and Sketch have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8h69.png)

In the storyboard, I added a NSMenuItem, called Rename..., under File and I linked it to an action called renameDocument (which I believe already implemented in Cocoa). I thought that would be enough, but it wasn't. I thought about overriding the rename method, but I think this should be an easy solution because I think a lot of OS X applications have the same renaming features. I searched through Stack Overflow and google and I got no answers.

My question is: Is there a specific UI element in AppKit which allows me to achieve a similar goal to what Pages and Sketches have done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You get the Rename functionality for free if you switch [autosaving in place](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515106-autosavesinplace) on.

Comment: I already switch autosaving in place to on, but that won't let me rename the file

Comment: I am also currently having trouble with this at the moment. Can you please elaborate? Are there any other additional steps to take?

Comment: Create a new document based project in Xcode. Add some code to prevent the throw in `data(ofType:)`. Make sure `autosavesInPlace` returns true. Does this test app do what you want?